# unresolved inclusion WProgram.h

Tags: c++, avr

Eclipse is able to find iostream, stdio.h and conio.h

But it is not able to locate Wprogram.h

I am using Indigo on windows8 with CDT. I am able to compile and run a hello world program.
I have also linked the AVR directory.
Does any one know why eclipse can not locate the header file?

Comment: More details, please.  Show us some code, and if you are getting compiler or linker errors, please show the complete error message.  Don't paraphrase.  Details about your specific platform (OS/compiler toochain, etc) in the form of tags would also help.

Comment: Because I am a new member it wont let me add a picture. I tried to post my code and my include paths

Answer (score 1):

The header file either doesn't exist or the path to it's directory isn't in the includes path. Check Project -> Properties -> c/c++ build -> Settings -> includes -> include paths and make sure the folder that Wprogram.h is in is included in that list.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search suggests that Wprogram.h has been renamed to Arduino.h. Try including that file instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I added Arduino.h cleaned the project than saved it and rebuilt.
However it was not able to find that either.
I am also including via paths and symbols
C:\arduino-1.0.3\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include
C:\arduino-1.0.3\hardware\tools\avr\avr\bin
C:\arduino-1.0.3\hardware\tools\avr\bin

Answer (score 0):

It's often not obvious which file is causing the import of old (and not existing) `Wprogram.h`. Thus scan your last imported libs (the .h and .c) file for `#Include "Wprogram.h"` and replace by `#Include "Arduino.h"`